# There is no antipode-preserving map $f:S^{n+1}\rightarrow S^n$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am trying to prove that there is no antipode-preserving map $f:S^{n+1}\rightarrow S^n$.  Here is what I have:

Suppose there is an antipode-preserving map $f:S^{n+1}\rightarrow S^n$.  If we restrict $f$ the the "equator" $S^n$ then we have an antipode-preserving map $S^n\rightarrow S^n$, so $f$ must be nullhomotopic.  But the restriction of $f$ extends continuously to the hemisphere $D^{n+1}$, so the degree of $f$ must be zero which is a contradicton.

I am not at all satisfied with this proof.  I would like a proof that does not assume that there is no antipode-preserving map $S^n\rightarrow S^n$ that is nullhomotopic.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Could you please indicate what topological tools you have available (e.g., singular homoology), or in what course/context the question arises?

Comment: I am studying for a qualifying exam in Topology/Algebraic Topology, so homology is fair game.  However, we did not cover cohomology theory in the course nor did we cover the universal coefficient theorem used below.  This question in particular is a problem out of Lawson's Topology: A Geometric Approach in the chapter on the fundamental group.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use the fact about maps $S^n\to S^n$?  It's quite a common approach for proving this statement.

Comment: I don't have the result given in my course material.  I was trying to find a way to prove it with only the given material, but perhaps this is not possible.

Comment: @1234 In that case, rather than try to find a proof that there is no antipodes-preserving map from $S^{n+1}\to S^n$ without using the result about antipodes-preserving maps $S^n\to S^n$, I suggest that you try and get hold of a proof of the $S^n\to S^n$ result so that you can use it to prove the $S^{n+1}\to S^n$ result.

Comment: I think the proof comes from Allen Hatcher's. You might be satisfied if you fill in the details. The inclusion map $i:S^n →D^{n+1}$ is nulhomotopic. Just define $F:S^n×I→D^{n+1}$ by $F(x,t)=x/(1-t)$ and $x/0=0$. Then we see that the map $f∘F$ is a homotopy between $f∘i=f$ and a constant map. So the induced map $f*:H_n(S^n)→H_n(S^n)$ and the zero map $0:H_n(S^n)→H_n(S^n)$ are the same, which means that $f*=0$.

Comment: @Deepleeqe Thanks for that, but we were more interested in the proof that any antipodes-preserving map $S^n\to S^n$ has odd degree.  A proof of that fact can also be found in Hatcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we consider $S^{n}$ as a subset of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, then we get a continuous map $S^{n+1}\to\mathbb R^{n+1}$.  By the [Borsuk-Ulam Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem), such a map must map two antipodal points in $S^{n+1}$ to the same point.  In particular, these two antipodal points are not mapped to antipodal points in $S^n$.

---

Alternatively, prove it directly - if $f\colon S^{n+1}\to S^n$ preserves antipodes, then it induces a map $f'\colon \mathbb RP^{n+1}\to\mathbb RP^n$.  Now, the cohomology ring of $\mathbb RP^m$ with $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients is $\mathbb Z_2[\alpha]/(\alpha^{m+1})$, where $\alpha$ is the generator of $H^1(\mathbb RP^m\;;\;\mathbb Z_2)=\mathbb Z_2$.  So $f$ induces a map
$$
f^*\;\colon\;\mathbb Z_2[\alpha]/(\alpha^{n+1})\to\mathbb Z_2[\beta]/(\beta^{n+2})
$$
Since $f^*$ maps $H^1(\mathbb RP^{n})$ to $H^1(\mathbb RP^{n+1})$, it must map $\alpha$ either to $0$ or to $\beta$.  But the second case is impossible: then we have
$$
0=f^*(0)=f^*(\alpha^{n+1})=f^*(\alpha)^{n+1}=\beta^{n+1}\ne 0
$$
Therefore, $f^*(\alpha)=0$.

By the isomorphism given by the universal coefficient theorem, we see that the induced map on homology groups - 
$$
f_*\;\colon\;H_1(\mathbb RP^{n+1})\to H_1(\mathbb RP^n)
$$
 - is trivial also, and it follows that $f$ induces a trivial map on fundamental groups $\pi_1(\mathbb RP^{n+1})\to\mathbb RP^n)$ (since $\pi_1(\mathbb RP^m=\mathbb Z_2$).

It follows immediately that $f'$ satisfies the lifting criterion for the covering $S^n\to\mathbb RP^n$, so we get a lifting $\overline{f}\colon\mathbb RP^{n+1}\to S^n$.

Now compose $\overline f$ with the projection from $S^{n+1}$ to $\mathbb RP^{n+1}$ to get a map
$$
\overline{f}\circ\pi_{n+1}\;\colon \;S^{n+1}\xrightarrow{\pi}\mathbb RP^{n+1}\xrightarrow{\overline{f}}S^n
$$
We now have two maps $S^{n+1}\to S^n$ - our original map $f$ and $\overline{f}\circ\pi_{n+1}$, and we can readily see that they are both lifts of the map
$$
\pi_n\circ f\;\colon\;S^{n+1}\xrightarrow{f}S^n\xrightarrow{\pi_n}\mathbb RP^n
$$
The unique lifting property tells us that two such liftings are equal if they agree at a point.

Fix some point $x_0\in S^{n+1}$.  Then $\pi_{n+1}(x_0)=\pi_{n+1}(-x_0)$, so $\overline f\pi_{n+1}(x_0)=\overline f\pi_{n+1}(-x_0)$.  But $f(x_0)=-f(-x_0)$, so these maps are certainly not equal.  But now, by the definition of a lifting, we must have either $f(x_0)=\overline f\pi_{n+1}(x_0)$ or $f(-x_0)=\overline f\pi_{n+1}(-x_0)$ - so these two liftings agree at a point.  This is a contradiction.

Comment: The only version of the Borsuk-Ulam Theorem I have at my disposal is for maps $S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$.  I tried proving the theorem for arbitrary $n$ but I ended up using the facts above that I am trying to avoid.  Is there another way?

Comment: I have not yet covered cohomology theory or universal coefficient theorem.  Is there a more elementary proof?

Comment: @1234 The statement you are trying to prove is equivalent to the Borsuk-Ulam theorem.  One direction I have given in my answer.  For the other direction, suppose $f\colon S^n\to\mathbb R^n$ is continuous and does not map any pair of antipodal points to the same point.  Define $g\colon S^n\to S^{n-1}$ by setting $g(x) = (f(x) - f(-x))/|f(x) - f(-x)|$.  Then $g$ preserves antipodes, which we know to be impossible.

Comment: Thus, any proof of the Borsuk-Ulam gives you a proof of your fact and any proof of your fact gives you a proof of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem.  So if you're looking for help, I advise that you look up proofs of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem.  It's proved as Corollary 2B.7 in Hatcher (https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch2.pdf), but this proof is precisely the one that you are trying to avoid.  There's also a combinatorial proof from Tucker's Lemma given on the Wikipedia page.